# Undefined reference to "vtable for Menu"

Tags: c++, class

I'm trying to create a child class, on the class constructor I get the error `Undefined reference to "vtable for Menu"` which is strange since I have created many child classes with the same code.

```
class GameState
{
    public:
        virtual ~GameState(){};
        virtual void handle_events() = 0;
        virtual void logic() = 0;
        virtual void render() = 0;
};

class Level: public GameState
{
    private:
    public:
        Level();
        ~Level();
        void handle_events();
        void logic();
        void render();
};

Level::Level() // OK
{
}

~Level::Level()
{
}

class Menu : public GameState
{
    private:
    public:
        Menu();
        ~Menu();
        void handle_events();
        void logic();
        void render();
};

Menu::Menu() // ERROR
{
}

~Menu::Menu()
{
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/link-errs-missing-vtable.html Is that your whole code? If you are only compiling with that, it probably is complaining about the lack of definitions for the rest of your virtual functions.

Comment: This error message suggest that your destructor for main is not implemented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your tilde (~) is in the wrong place on the destructor:

```
~Menu::Menu()
{
}
```

should be:

```
Menu::~Menu()
{
}
```

You also need to provide the definitions for the other three virtual functions.